# Why am I seeing an "invalid parameter number" error when using named parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this error while I'm executing this SQL query with PDO:

> Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.

I cannot see what I need to change in my code.

Here is my code:

```
$req = $this->manager->dao->prepare('UPDATE pronostics 
                                SET draw_lottery = :drawLottery, result_rank = :resultRank
                                WHERE draw_date = :drawDate AND id_user = :IdUser 
                                AND lottery_name = :lotteryName');

$req->bindParam(':idUser', $idUser, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->bindParam(':drawLottery', $drawLottery, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(':resultRank', $resultRank, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->bindParam(':drawDate', $drawDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);        
$req->bindParam(':lotteryName', $lotteryName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
```

Could you tell me which parameter is missing?

Answer (score 2):

The `bindParam` strings are case sensitive, so `:idUser` must be capitalized the same way in your query and in your `bindParam` argument.

```
$req = $this->manager->dao->prepare('UPDATE pronostics 
                                    SET draw_lottery = :drawLottery, result_rank = :resultRank 
                                    WHERE draw_date = :drawDate AND id_user = :idUser AND lottery_name = :lotteryName');
$req->bindParam(':idUser', $idUser, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                    
$req->bindParam(':drawLottery', $drawLottery, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(':resultRank', $resultRank, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->bindParam(':drawDate', $drawDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(':lotteryName', $lotteryName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `UPDATE` query you said `AND id_user = :IdUser` whereas while defining the parameter the name is different as can be seen `$req->bindParam(':idUser'`. I believe that's the error. It should be same as mentioned in query `$req->bindParam(':IdUser'`